# Struts2 Portlet <s:file> fileupload tag giving null in Action after Submit

Tags: file-upload, struts2, portlet

I am working on a struts2 JSR 286 portlet and have to acheive fileupload functionality.

I am using fileupload struts2 tag with equivalent correct setter and getter methods inside the action class.

But I am not able to receive the file parameters and the content of it inside the Action class on Click of Submit button in the upload JSP.

Can anyone let me know whether fileupload tag doesn't support or work in struts2 portlet?

I am using struts 2.3.20.3 version.

Below is my code:

Here is my Struts2 Portlet

```
<portlet id="MyPortlet">
    <description xml:lang="EN">My Portlet</description>
    <portlet-name>MyPortlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="EN">my-portlet</display-name>

    <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr286Dispatcher</portlet-class>
```

My JSP Page

```
<s:form action="doUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<s:file name="upload" label="File"/>
<s:submit/>
```

Action Class:

```
 public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {
  private File file;
  private String contentType;
  private String filename;

  public void setUpload(File file) {
     this.file = file;
  }

  public void setUploadContentType(String contentType) {
     this.contentType = contentType;
  }

  public void setUploadFileName(String filename) {
     this.filename = filename;
  }

  public String execute() {
     //...
     return SUCCESS;
  }
```

struts.xml:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-portlet-default" namespace="/">
<action name="doUpload" class="com.example.UploadAction">    
<result name="success">upload_success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
```

Comment: Hi @AndreaLigios - Can you please look at the code I shared here?

Comment: Seems fine. Can you try changing the name of the attributes to respect their getters and setters?

Comment: @AndreaLigios , Changed the attribute/field name no change.Just for information my project is using OpenPortal Portelt Container.